# Graphing sqrt(x^3+x^2)*sin(pi/x) gives horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I have no idea how this website works, so i will do my best.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
minor tick num=1,
xlabel={$x$},
xmin=-5, xmax=5,
ylabel={$y$},
ymin=-5, ymax=5,
]
\addplot[blue, samples=200, domain=-1:5]{-sqrt(x^3+x^2)}
node[pos=0.3, pin=135:{\color{blue}$-\sqrt{x^3+x^2}$}]{};
\addplot[red, samples=500, domain=-1:5]{sqrt(x^3+x^2)*sin(pi/deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When i run the code (i did not include the other 200 lines of code) i get a horizontal line... just wondering if anyone knows a solution to this.

Thank you

Comment: When I compile your code it plots the function just fine, so maybe you have some conflicting definitions before this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you want to find out how this website works, read the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Generally, it would be nice if the code pasted in a question would be compilable in its own right, though in your case, we probably don't need to add that much code.

Comment: @GenericNickname So the red line for the second function is not almost flat?

Comment: When I tried compiling your code, I noticed lots of lines like this in the log: `NOTE: coordinate (2Y4.94975e0],3Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in y). ` That doesn't look healthy!

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry, didnt see the red line :) I'll post my answer below

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. No, it shoots off in the positive y direction after oscillating. Sorry, I shouldve posted it as a complete document

Comment: @DavidRobertson I am completely self taught so i have no idea what that even means. All i know is if it works or doesnt work. Thanks for the heads up though ill look into that

Comment: @TonyMau I think it's because you're asking pgf to compute sqrt(x^3 + x^2) when x^3 + x^2 could be negative. This happens when x < -1. , e.g. if x = -2, then the expression is -4. To prevent these errors from occuring, change the domain from `-5:5` to `-1:5`.

Comment: @DavidRobertson Thank you i made those revisions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After thinking for a bit: `sin` takes degrees as its input, which is why you're using `deg(x)`. However, you're comparing this to `pi`, which is used for radians. This is why you get the wrong plot. Below I show three ways of getting it right.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    minor tick num=1,
    xlabel={$x$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=1,
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    ]
    \addplot[red, samples=1000, domain=-5:5]{sqrt(x^3+x^2)*sin(deg(pi/x))};
    \addplot[cyan,dashed, samples=1000, domain=-5:5]{sqrt(x^3+x^2)*sin(180/x)};
    \addplot[blue,densely dotted, samples=1000, domain=-5:5, trig format=rad]{sqrt(x^3+x^2)*sin(pi/x)};
    \addplot[blue, samples=200, domain=-5:5]{-sqrt(x^3+x^2)} node[pos=0.3, pin=135:{\color{blue}$-\sqrt{x^3+x^2}$}]{};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dude you're a genius, thank you so much... I cant believe I didn't think of that! The first one fixed it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a line because in my opinion you shouldn't use "deg(x)". Try it with just "sin(deg(pi/x))" and see if it fits your needs more.

Comment: I tried that, it gives a better result but it doesn't give the correct graph. I used deg(x) in all my other graphs and it seems to work fine there.

Comment: @TonyMau Are you sure it's not the right graph? You may want to adjust your xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax values to show the "whole" graph...

Comment: yes I am sure, I'm using the graph off of my TI-89 as a reference and they are not the same graph.

Comment: Is [this the kind of plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt(x%5E3%2Bx%5E2)*sin(pi%2Fx)) you were expecting?

Comment: @GenericNickname You are right that there is an issue with `deg`, but the actual solution is, I believe `sin(deg(pi/x))`. Could you correct your answer? Welcome to TeX.SE by the way.